# Possible degrees of an algebraic element in intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Suppose I'm given a field extension $K\subset L\subset K(\alpha)$ with $[K(\alpha):K]=d\in \Bbb{N}$. Then find all possible values of the degree $[L(\alpha):L]$. It's easy to observe that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$ divides the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ and hence $[L(\alpha):L]\le d$. Can someone give an example such that there are intermediate fields for which all possible values are achieved?

**Edit:**

Can this example works? Let $[K(\alpha):K]=d$ where $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $X^d-2$. By Eisenstein $X^d-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. Then for any divisor $d'$ of $d$, we consider $L=\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ where $\beta$ is a root of $X^{d'}-2$. Since $\beta=\alpha^{d/d'}$, $L\subset \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $[L(\alpha):L]=\frac{[K(\alpha):K]}{[L:K]}=\frac{d}{d'}$. Thus we can achieve all divisors of $d$ as degrees of intermediate fields. Is this description correct?

Comment: I think you might want to say $[K(\alpha):K] = d \in \Bbb N$. ***Cheers!***

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: Note that $L(\alpha)=K(\alpha)$. Also, note that there are divisibility restrictions on the degree.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That means $[L(\alpha):L]\mid d$. So can we get all possible divisors of $d$ as $[L(\alpha):L]$ for intermediate fields? Can you give an example for any arbitrary $d$?

Comment: Not necessarily. There can be a field extension of degree $mn$ with no intermediate field of degree $m$. This is easier to see, once you've learned some Galois Theory. The group $A_4$ (alternating group on four elements) has order $12$ but no subgroup of order six. In Galois Theory it's proved that subfields correspond to subgroups, so a field extension with Galois group $A_4$ (hence, degree $12$) will have no intermediate field of index six, thus, no subfield of degree four.

Comment: On the other hand, if the Galois group is *abelian* of order $d$, then it has subgroups of all orders dividing $d$, so there will be subfields of all degrees dividing $d$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson is it possible to have an abelian Galois Group of any order $d$?

Comment: Yes, given any finite group $G$, there are fields $F\subset K$ with $G$ the Galois group of $K$ as an extension of $F$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117753/discussion-between-backbone-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have added a description as an edit. Is it correct?

Comment: $\beta=\alpha^{d/d'}$ is not necessarily right. Better to *define* $\beta$ by $\beta=\alpha^{d/d'}$, then note that $\beta$ so defined is a root of $x^{d/d'}-2$, etc. Oh, sorry, I don't do chat.